# How to upgrade to latest KDE Plasma, on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, kde-plasma-5

I seem to be stuck on 5.18.8 of Plasma - even though I've updated apt - do I need to manually add a different source?

I've run sudo apt-get update, and looked in "Discover" and software updates on Ubuntu.

I also ran "pkcon refresh", then "pkcon update" per @chetzz 's idea below. The former seemed to do a lot of work, but the latter, said no work to do.

No errors anywhere.

Comment: What messages or errors do you see? What command(s) are you running to make it update?

Comment: sudo apt-get update, and looking in "Discover" and software updates on Ubuntu.  I also ran "pkcon refresh", then "pkcon update" per @chetzz 's idea below.  The  former seemed to do a lot of work, but the latter, said no work to do.  No errors anywhere.

Comment: This info should be added to the question. Using the edit button is strongly encouraged because it makes them better, and better able to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pkcon refresh
pkcon update
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).